# Showing that a functions derivative is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable but not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|f'|$ is not bounded on  $\mathbb{R}$.

So I know that to show that $|f'|$ isn't bounded you would have to show that for any constant B, $|f'(a)|$ $>$ $B$, for some $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Try to prove that if $|f^\prime|$ is bounded then $f$ is uniformly continuous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $A\Rightarrow B \iff \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.

Assume that for $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ differentiable and $|f'|$ bounded it follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous (to be more precise, it is Lipschitz continuous).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the counterpositive.

**Claim:** If $f: I \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable such that $|f'(x)| < M$, $\forall x \in I$, for some $M > 0$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**Proof:** Use the Mean Value Theorem and show that it is Lipschitz.